# Does shell scripts in Jenkins pipeline run asynchronously?

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline for building my android application. In some stages, I have shell scripts. when I run the stages one by one(by commenting others) everything works fine, but when I run them all together I see strange behavior.

It seems that the shell scripts are running in **parallel** !!

here is my jenkinsfile :

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("Clean"){
          agent{
            node{
              label 'master'
              customWorkspace getMainDirectory()
            }
          }
          steps{
              sh """#!/bin/bash
                rm -rf Corona
                rm -rf native-corona-android
                cd ..
                cp -a TemplateWorkspace/. ${getCoronaBranch()}-${getNativeBrach()}
                """
          }
        }
        stage("pull native repo"){
            agent{
              node{
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace getNativeProjectPath()
              }
            }
            steps{
                echo "pulling native"
                git(
                   url: nativeRepositoryAddress,
                   credentialsId: credentialsId,
                   branch: getNativeBrach()
                )
                echo "pulling done"
            }
        }
        stage("pull corona repo"){
            agent{
              node{
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace getCoronaProjectPath()
              }
            }
            steps{
                echo "pulling corona"
                git(
                   url: coronaRepositoryAddress,
                   credentialsId: credentialsId,
                   branch: getCoronaBranch()
                )
                echo "pulling done"
            }
        }
        stage("build"){
            environment {
                docDir = getMainDirectory()
                ANDROID_HOME = getAndroidSDKLocation()
            }
            agent{
              node{
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace getNativeProjectPath()
              }
            }
            steps{
                sh """#!/bin/bash
                ./gradlew clean
                ./gradlew changeFiles --stacktrace --no-daemon
                ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --no-daemon
                """
            }
        }
        stage("move build files"){
          agent{
            node{
              label 'master'
              customWorkspace getGradleBuildLocation()
            }
          }
          steps{
              sh """#!/bin/bash
                yes | cp -rf * ../../../../JenkinsBuilds/${getOutputFolder()}/
                """
          }
        }
    }

}
```

I just want to run steps synchronous(and of course shell scripts), What is my problem?

Here is what I see:

In "Clean" step the folders get deleted and a fresh copy of Template folders get copied to work directory. Steps "pull native repo" and "pull corona repo" do the jobs they should do. but in step "build" I can see that a part of "native-corona-android" files is gone and "gradlew" script is deleted. I have also seen situations where the whole "native-corona-android" folder gets deleted. Then I thought that the script in "Clean" step is called again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using `parallel` directive all steps should be running synchronously.

What behavior do you observe? Which steps are running parallel?

Comment: I have added more details to question.

Comment: Is this behavior deterministic? 
Did you debug what is the content of your workspace after each step. 
Also you are using cutsom workspace paths. Are they properly generated?
Is your `gradlew` pulled from repository or do you provision it externally?

Comment: No, this process is not deterministic, every time I build, I see different behavior but this the process that happens the most, custom Workspace paths are methods that just return static strings, and `gradlew` is pulled in `pull native repo` stage